# StreamLabs socket API using Java

Tags: java, websocket, twitch

I am trying to connect to streamLabs socket API using Java. The API url is

`https://sockets.streamlabs.com?token=<socketToken>`

This doesnt work because Java expects the socket to be `ws://...`. When I change it to "ws" format it gives a connection timeout.

Am I missing something? Is this not actually a websocket, if not how would it work?

Here is a link to their documentation: https://streamlabs.readme.io/docs/socket-api

More info: I have tried with both `org.asynchttpclient.ws.WebSocket` and `javax.websocket` neither are working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using SocketIo

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>io.socket</groupId>
     <artifactId>socket.io-client</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Their socket documentation is definitely lacking, their actual websocket url you will be connecting to is
`wss://sockets.streamlabs.com/socket.io/?token=<your_socket_api_token>&transport=websocket`

Additionally, since it's not really mentioned anywhere, they use an integer, prepended to their messages, as a message type indicator.

- `0` is the init message type, containing heartbeat interval and timeout
- `40` is the ping message you will be sending and receiving
- `41` is invalid token message you will get after connecting with an invalid token
- `42` will be the actual streamlabs event messages you will be getting

At least that's what I've gathered so far from poking around a bit.